# MingGW-w64 usage

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

I recently installed MinGW-w64.
Now I wanted to compile a sample program but I got an important question:

How do I compile with 32 bit or 64 bit?
I found a lib and a lib32 directory, so there must be a way to compile both.

But how do I compile it for 32 bit and 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here to determine what toolchain you have based on name of the file that you downloaded:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/download%20filename%20structure

(It is expected to start "mingw-w32" or "mingw-w64" and support 32 bit targets in the first case or 64 bit targets in the second case).

If you download a toolchain for 64 bit target, so probably it will be capable to produce 32 bit target as well if you use

```
-m32
```

option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile for 64-bit use 64-bit compiler

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

If you want to compile for 32-bit use 32-bit compiler

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

hope this helps